# CSS Border Draw

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want CSS transitions border `fieldset` as check-mark circle, how is it?

```css
.checkmark__circle {
  stroke-dasharray: 166;
  stroke-dashoffset: 166;
  stroke-width: 2;
  stroke-miterlimit: 10;
  stroke: #7ac142;
  fill: none;
  animation: stroke 0.6s cubic-bezier(0.65, 0, 0.45, 1) forwards;
}

.checkmark {
  width: 56px;
  height: 56px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: block;
  stroke-width: 2;
  stroke: #fff;
  stroke-miterlimit: 10;
  margin: 10% auto;
  box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px #7ac142;
  animation: fill .4s ease-in-out .4s forwards, scale .3s ease-in-out .9s both;
}

.checkmark__check {
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  stroke-dasharray: 48;
  stroke-dashoffset: 48;
  animation: stroke 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.65, 0, 0.45, 1) 0.8s forwards;
}

@keyframes stroke {
  100% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}
@keyframes scale {
  0%, 100% {
    transform: none;
  }
  50% {
    transform: scale3d(1.1, 1.1, 1);
  }
}
@keyframes fill {
  100% {
    box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 30px #7ac142;
  }
}
```

```html
<fieldset style=" border: 1px solid #7ac142; border-radius: 10px; ">
    <legend>
        <svg class="checkmark" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 52 52">
            <circle class="checkmark__circle" cx="26" cy="26" r="25" fill="none"></circle>
            <path class="checkmark__check" fill="none" d="M14.1 27.2l7.1 7.2 16.7-16.8"></path>
        </svg>
    </legend>
    <div class="span12 space-3" style=" font-weight: bold; font-size: 18px; text-align: center; ">
        Hello World!
    </div>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: Try to refrain from using 'inline' styles if you can.  As for animating your border, what all have you tried?  Keep in mind that stackoverflow isn't a place to ask others to do the work for you.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Paulie_D i want transitions border fieldset example this: https://jsfiddle.net/n97cteve/ but without hover.what do I do?

Comment: you might do this with css http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/IGliC  turn hover and transition into a single animation

Comment: @GCyrillus i want transitions border without hover just with loading page.

Comment: turn this code (or from any other one you have) into an animation (@keyframes) instead :hover (just repeating :) give it a try , we'll still be here to help where you have trouble :)

Answer (score 0):

Following your fiddle:

Remove the `:hover` from the `svg-wrapper` rule and set a new class for the shape state as `.complete`, in CSS:

```
.svg-wrapper .shape.complete { /* Instead of .svg-wrapper:hover .shape */
  stroke-width: 2px;
  stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  stroke-dasharray: 760;
}
```

Using Javascript, ensure the shape has been created in the DOM structure and trigger the state change by adding the class `complete` to the shape:

```
(function shapeReady() {
  var svgShape = document.querySelector('.svg-wrapper .shape');
  if (!svgShape) {setTimeout(shapeReady, 50); return;}
  svgShape.classList.add('complete');
})();
```

Comment: Thank you for your response,How can use it in my code: https://jsfiddle.net/x93qf4xk/ start transitions border from check-mark circle, what do I do?

Comment: No worries. I'd suggest you to work on adapting the solution to your own needs, and if you get stuck in some technical issue, ask again, me and others will come to assist. But you have to work first :)